# CrossCursor in matplotlib backend does not appear

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, cursor

In an PyQt environment I want to change the cursor to a crosshair inside a `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg` object, but if I put `canvas.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))` (`canvas` is the corresponding canvas object), nothing happens; not even an error is raised.

Comment: Have you checked whether the edge color is none, white, etc or the edge width is 0? Without a visible edge some markers of matplotlib become very faint.

Comment: I should have been more precise in the question: The Cursor remains as the standard mouse arrow and does not disappear